# родившемся или родившимся

Tags: орфография, согласование, падежи

Подскажите,пожалуйста, **е** или **и** нужно писать в слове *родивше(и)мся*?

**Советский Союз развалился при первом же генсеке, родивше(и)мся после 1917 года.**

Comment: Зря Вы отменили правку. 1. Обычный заголовок всегда начинается с большой буквы. 2. После запятой всегда есть пробел. 3. Заглавные буквы внутри слов заголовка позволяют сразу понять — в чем дело? на ЧТО надо обратить внимание?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: (при каком?) *при родивш**е**мся* (предложный падеж ед. числа).

"Родивш**и**мся" соответствует творительному падежу единственного числа (каким /генсек**о**м/) или дательному падежу множественного числа (каким /генсек**а**м/).

Answer (score 2):

*Советский Союз развалился при первом же генсеке, родивш**е**мся после 1917 года.*

Для того, чтобы понять **е** или **и** нужно написать в причастии, необходимо определить его падеж.
Развалился (при ком? П. п.) **при генсеке** (каком?) — это определяемое слово, оно требует постановки причастия также в предложном падеже — [родившемся](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F).